# How to make a knowledge Representation in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have some information:

- X is organism if X is human, animal or plant.
- X is organism if X can breathe and move.
- Mammal, reptile, amphibian, fish, and bird is animal.
- Fish breathe with gills, have scales, oviparous, and have fin.
- Bird breathe with lungs, oviparous, and have wings.
- Mammal breathe with lungs and viviparous.
- Reptile breathe with lungs, have scales, and ovoviviparous.
- Amphibian breathe with lungs and viviparous.
- Plant can produce oxygen.
- Human and animal cannot produce oxygen.

I made a rules by this information:

```
organism :- human; animal; plant
organism :- can_breathe, can_move.

animal :- mammal.
animal :- fish.
animal :- reptile.
animal :- amphibian.
animal :- bird.

fish :- breathe_with_gills, have_scales, oviparous, have_fin.
bird :- breathe_with_lungs, oviparous, have_wings.
mammal :- breathe_with_lungs, viviparous.
reptile :- breathe_with_lungs, have_scales, ovoviviparous.
amphibian :- breathe_with_lungs, viviparous.

plant :- produce_oxygen.
human :- not(produce_oxygen).
animal :- not(produce_oxygen).
```

Then, I tried to use it in prolog and use assert to add facts in the knowledge base. I want the output like this:

```
?- assert(animal).
true.
?- organism.
true.
```

But I got output like this:

```
?- assert(animal).
ERROR: No permission to modify static procedure `animal/0'
ERROR: Defined at c:/users/user/documents/prolog/file.pl:4
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [10] assert(animal)
ERROR:    [9] <user>
```

How could I fix it?

Comment: What do you think `assert` does?

Comment: it use to manually add fact to knowledge base, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but you already have a definition of how to prove `animal` in your code, which your `assert` is (in effect) trying to modify.  Similarly, if you can prove `animal`, you don't need to assert `organism`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not `assert` things you have specificed how to prove in your code (and don't need to); you should `assert` things cannot be proven any other way (`produce_oxygen`, for example).

Comment: Thank you for helping me. But I have question, how to prove an organism just by proving that it is a plant or animal? I got some exception that want me to answer such as `breathe_with_lungs` or else

Comment: You already have a rule that says it is an organism if it is either a plant or an animal (or human), and another that says if it can both breathe and move.  Not knowing anything about how this "exception" occurred, can't help much there.